# Button doesn't work in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I become really confused ! I want to design online shopping web site and I create new empty asp.net web site in visual studio 2013 with framework 4.5 and I write Register.aspx with the following code:

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void registerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbReport.Text ="it works";   
    }
```

**Register.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
      <script>
           (function ($) {
               // constants
               var SHOW_CLASS = 'show',
                   HIDE_CLASS = 'hide',
                   ACTIVE_CLASS = 'active';

               $('.tabs').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   var $tab = $(this),
                        href = $tab.attr('href');

                   $('.active').removeClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);
                   $tab.addClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);

                   $('.show')
                      .removeClass(SHOW_CLASS)
                      .addClass(HIDE_CLASS)
                      .hide();

                   $(href)
                     .removeClass(HIDE_CLASS)
                     .addClass(SHOW_CLASS)
                     .hide()
                     .fadeIn(550);
               });
           })(jQuery);
   </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="body-logIn">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="flat-form-register">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="LogIn.aspx">ورود</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Register.aspx" class ="active">ثبت نام</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="ResetPass.aspx">تغییرپسورد</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             <div id="register" class="form-action show">
                    <h1>ثبت نام</h1>
                        <p>. ازاین که می خواهید عضوی ازفروشگاه من باشید بسیار متشکریم،بهترین لحظات را درفروشگاه من برای شما آرزومندیم</p>
                <form class="form-Account">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="userText" runat="server" cssClass="logInTextBox" PlaceHolder="نام کاربری" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="passText" runat="server" TextMode="Password" cssClass="logInTextBox" PlaceHolder="پسورد"></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="confirmPassText" runat="server" TextMode="Password" cssClass="logInTextBox"  PlaceHolder="تکرار پسورد"></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="nameText" runat="server" cssClass="logInTextBox" PlaceHolder="نام و نام خانوادگی"></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="emailText" runat="server" cssClass="logInTextBox" PlaceHolder="آدرس الکترونیکی"></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="mphoneText" runat="server" cssClass="logInTextBox" PlaceHolder="شماره همراه"></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                             <asp:button ID="registerBtn"  runat ="server" Text="ثبت کنید" class="button" OnClick="registerBtn_Click" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label ID ="lbReport" Text="Hello world" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                     
                </form>
            </div>
                <div id="LogIn" class="form-action hide"></div>
                <div id="RessetPass" class="form-action hide"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

But when I click on the button nothing happens it seems that registerBtn_Click is not called ! what can I do ? how can I fix this issues?

Comment: Add your code to the question(not all code, just relevant to the question), do not paste links here. **A suggestion:** Put break point on the event handler `registerBtn_Click` to check whether it fires

Comment: why don't you use `<asp:Button />` to create your buttons?

Comment: I put break point but it doesn't fire ! my problem is this that why it doesn't fire ???/

Comment: It seems that the problem is with my MasterPage.master because when I create a new web form and I copy the whole content of <div class="body-logIn"><div/> in it ! it works fine ! it seems that master page doesn't allow the function to be called! what is wrong?

Comment: where is your jquery library included

Comment: I include them at the end of my master page before </form>! I use empty MasterPage.master with no jquery or any html and it has no problem !

Comment: Thanks every one for your help ! it was because of one wrong <form> in my Master.master  !

Answer (score 2):

You are using incorrect markup for the `button` i.e. `<asp:button>` .

Try using `<asp:Button>`

```
<asp:Button ID="registerBtn"  runat ="server" Text="ثبت کنید" class="button" OnClick="registerBtn_Click" />
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference !It doesn't work either!

Comment: That is not the problem, it works fine with both syntax.